# How should the EFI partition be handled in a software raid?

Tags: arch-linux, grub, raid, mdadm

I am trying to install Arch onto a computer, I have two storage devices.
I partitioned the drives identically as I would if I were installing to one storage device on efi dekstop.

```
sda
  sda1 (boot partition)
  sda2 (swap)
  sda3 (root)
sdb
  sdb1
  sdb2
  sdb3
```

I then created created an array for each partition

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

Leaving me with 3 arrays.

```
md0 (boot)
md1 (swap)
md2 (root)
```

I then formatted each array as I would if they were single partions, i.e: `mkfs.ext4 /dev/md2`, `mkfs.fat /dev/md0`, `mkswap /dev/md1`. I then mounted the arrays as normal and went through the standard installation.

However, when trying to install grub to the mount point of `/dev/md0`, I received an error saying

```
efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Operation not permitted
```

I know this is misconfiguration of the boot partition, but I am unsure how the boot device should be handled in a EFI installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EFI firmware neither understands, nor reads Linux software raid partitions.

You need to drop `mdraid` for EFI system partition(s) and leave them be as real FAT32 partitions. It's OK to simply clone them using `dd` or even `cat` though I wouldn't recommend doing that if you mount them using `UUID`. You can mount either of them using `PARTUUID` instead. If you change any files in `/boot/efi` don't forget to clone it [the changes] after remounting it `ro`.

Alternatively you could add an extra boot-only disk (HDD/SSD/NVMe).